# Request fails due to CORS issue with origin from localhost

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, cors, http-headers

I have seen dozens of questions on SO and different blogs talking about this with "answers" -- all to no avail.

I have a React.js app on my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04).  Locally, I try to test it by running `npm start` and it opens up the browser  to http://localhost:3000.

On one page, I am trying to access my PHP api which is on my shared hosting server.

Chrome and Firefox both say that it fails due to server not having `Access-Control-Allow-Orgin`.

Exact Message:

```
Failed to load http://---/api/v1/categories: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost.com:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
localhost.com/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

However, upon my php server entry point I do have:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
```

Here is where I make my api call in my react app:

```
 componentDidMount() {

  var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
        "Access-Control-Request-Method": "*"
    },
  }

  // I have since removed the headers from the options as advised in the comments 
  fetch('http://---/api/v1/categories', options)
  .then(results => {
    return results.json();
  }).then(data => {
    let categories = data.map((category) => {
      return(
        // edited out
      )
    })
    this.setState({categories: categories});
  })
 }
}
```

I have tried this on both Chrome and Firefox; I have also tried to alias my server away from localhost.  I have tried the `no-cors` approach, which does get me access -- but breaks everything of course.  I have tried with and without passing headers along with my `fetch` request.

**UPDATE**:

I did get it to work by installing [this Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en).  I feel this is a workaround and would like to know if there is a coding answer here.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Orgin - try Access-Control-Allow-Origin, would that be it?

Comment: Neither `Access-Control-Request-Headers` nor `Access-Control-Request-Method` allow a `*` wildcard value. The first one needs to be a list of actual request headers that the request will use, and the second one has to specify _one_ request method. But you are making a run-of-the-mill GET request here, not even sending credentials - so what are you setting those headers for in the first place? They are for cases that require a _pre-flight_ request - which a normal GET doesn't.

Comment: @CBroe  Ok, so I remove the headers in the request (as stated in the question), it still doesn't work.  So this is not the issue by itself.  But still good info to know, thanks.

Comment: Quote the exact error message please.

Comment: @CBroe added the message; there are two, not sure if the second is related.

Comment: @CBroe  Origin was mispelled, thus causing the entire issue.  How embarrassing.  Answer added below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

`Origin` was misspelled as `Orgin`.

This typo has existed in my project for almost three years.  This was the first time I needed to use cross-domain access.

Answer (score -1):

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
```

Should be:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH");
```

...and any other methods you intend to accept.