# How to fetch data from server using JavaScript? (adding backend to React app for the first time)

Tags: php, reactjs, xampp

I have been working on a simple web app/game using React.js. I am trying to learn more about backend development, so I would like to add a database to my application to store high scores. To be honest, I am bit overwhelmed and am having trouble getting started. My problem so far is I cannot actually figure out how to fetch data from php code on the server in my JavaScript.

My general plan was to download XAMPP, write PHP code that queries a SQL database, and then retrieve data from the server by fetching data from the PHP page. I created a new react app using npx create-react-app, and started the Apache server on XAMPP.

Inside of the componentDidMount() function of the React page, I tried:

```
fetch("http://localhost/test/", {mode: 'no-cors'})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
```

But the response body is empty. I believe this is because 'no-cors' results in an opaque response since you are not supposed to fetch resources cross-origin.

I found one post suggesting that converting the response to JSON could help somehow, so I also tried

```
fetch("http://localhost/test/", {mode: 'no-cors'})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
    console.log(json)
})
```

When I try this, I get the error "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input"

Inside of my test.php in the XAMPP folder, I have:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: application/json');
<?php
  $myObj = new stdClass();
  $myObj->name = "John";
  $myObj->age = 30;
  $myObj->city = "New York";

  $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

  echo $myJSON;
?>
```

I also tried just echoing "Hello world". At this point I'm not really concerned with the format or content of the data I'm trying to pass; I just want to pass data from the PHP to the JavaScript.

I suppose the problem stems from the fact that everything is being hosted locally? I access my React app to test at localhost:3000, and the php page can be accessed at localhost/test/. I am mainly working on this project for the sake of my own learning and to get some experience with the back end as I look for my first job after graduation, so I don't really care if it is actually hosted online or not.

If anyone can help me figure out how to get this working or what the best path forward here is I would really appreciate it! Is using XAMPP/PHP even the right approach here? Hopefully this question makes sense...

edit:Thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing the URL in my react code to http://127.0.0.1/test/. However I had an identical result. Is there anything in the server configuration I should change as well?

Comment: In my experience React doesn't like localhost. Try changing it to   http:127.0.0.1/test.

Comment: What's the output of the command `curl http://localhost/test/`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my code working. One big problem was that I put my php header outside of the php tags. I also had to actually return response.json() in the first .then. A very similar question was asked here:
[Request fails due to CORS issue with origin from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955928/request-fails-due-to-cors-issue-with-origin-from-localhost)

My working code is as follows:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");

  $myObj = new stdClass();
  $myObj->name = "John";
  $myObj->age = 30;
  $myObj->city = "New York";

  $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

  echo $myJSON;
?>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost/test/")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

The JSON object containing name, age, and city location is successfully logged to the console. Sorry for the dumb question, but I appreciate the help nonetheless.