# CORSS with proxy url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cross-domain

I am making a react application where I use an API. However, I couldn't make the API work and I opted for CROSS, using a proxy URL (https://yacdn.org/proxy/). Now I can retrieve my desired information from the API but after some time my application crashes.
I get an error saying:

Access to fetch at 'https://yacdn.org/proxy/https://apps.des.qld.gov.au/species/?op=getspecies&kingdom=animals&family=Macropodidae' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I tried using mode: 'no-cors'. I am not allowed to use [Chrome-extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en) and was told to come up with a backend solution that just forwards (proxies) the call to the API and returns the result

How can I solve this? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request fails due to CORS issue with origin from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955928/request-fails-due-to-cors-issue-with-origin-from-localhost)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fetch` to achieve this:

```
fetch('https://cors.io/?https://apps.des.qld.gov.au/species/?op=getspecies&kingdom=animals&family=Macropodidae',
     {
        method: 'GET'
     })
     .then(res => {
       res.text().then((s) => console.log(JSON.parse(s)))
     })
     .catch(error => {
        // Handle your error
        throw new Error('Failed while checking data from au services:' + error)
     })
```

Use this proxy server:
`https://cors.io/?...`

And also for the response is important to convert into JSON object:

`res.text().then((s) => console.log(JSON.parse(s)))`

Hope it help you.

Comment: I tried with mode: 'no-cors' but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry Nahida. I updated the code above. Could you please test it and see if it works?

Comment: Those are response headers; setting them in the request does nothing.

Comment: SLaks you are right. I tested without the Header and it works. Answer updated.